# What are the common procedures for viewing suspensions of volatile organic compounds under an optical microscope?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I am looking to measure a mixture of triethylamine and water in a micro-Raman instrument. This involves placing the sample under an optical microscope. The "default" sample preparation is to place the sample on a microscope slide.

However, that is not an acceptable solution for my use case. Triethylamine is a volatile substance with a foul odor. A thin film of the substance on a glass slide would quickly evaporate, making the measurement pointless and introducing toxic vapors into my university's shared facility (there is no forced ventilation, like a fume hood, available).

Are there sample containers or procedures for viewing volatile substances under an optical microscope?

Comment: There are microscope slides which have a mild depression in them. You can add more liquid and cover it. Those slides are called slides with reaction wells. It takes much longer to evaporate now if the wells are covered. BTW, triethylamine and water is not that volatile! Try neat alcohol and it will evaporate in less than a minute.

Comment: The point is that the micro Raman set up should not give you any advantage, at least not for what you've described